# browser omits white space from string but that is visible in view source and I want to keep that space in browser display

Tags: html

I am getting an issue regarding the whitespace in my database string
browser omits white space from string but that is visible in view source and I want to keep that space in browser display

In my database a string is stored like this:
"         test string test string test string    "
(with white space before and after the actual string)

and I want that original string to be displayed in browser but it omits the strting and ending white spaces

can anyone suggest me what I will have to do?

Comment: try using `&nbsp;` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: @Ejay
thank for the reply,
I have tried this but did not worked for me...
it takes white space not &nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the preceding and succeeding blank with `&nbsp;` (a non-breaking space, as HTML otherwise may ignore your whitespace), or use `<pre>...</pre>` wrapped around the specific parts. This means the whitespace will be respected, but it does not mean that you will *see* it... for spotting it easily you can consider changing the background-color of that non-breaking space via a wrapping span with appropriate CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is transform the text *after* it's been retrieved from the database and *before* it's displayed.

As Phillip said, you can replace the `' '` characters with `'&nbsp;'`

So, if your database contains the text (".  test string  test string  .") then you can use preg_replace to convert that to `".&nbsp;&nbsp;test&nbsp;string&nbsp;&nbsp;test&nbsp;string&nbsp;&nbsp;."`

E.g

```
$curStr = ".  test string  test string  .";
$curStrTransformed = preg_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $curStr);
```

// $curStr now = `".&nbsp;&nbsp;test&nbsp;string&nbsp;&nbsp;test&nbsp;string&nbsp;&nbsp;."`

This displays as:
".  test string  test string  ."